# Azure Data Factory Copy Task OnPremises DB to Azure Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Am trying to copy data tables from On-Premises MSSQL to Azure SQL Tables.

My setting for Table Option on Sink Tab of Copy Activity is to set to 'Auto Create Table' (This will automatically create sink table if doesn't exists and this doesn't support using blob storage as staging.)

When executed with above setting it never finishes and it just shows status in progress.

But when source is other than MSSQL it works fine.  Tested with CSV files and Oracle db.

[image]

If I set Table Option to None, i can enable staging, but now it expects to have target table defined before it loads.

[image]

Any clues why it's not working for MSSQL ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the same operation with you and don't get the error:

[image]

Sink dataset

[image]

Operation: Auto create table:

[image]

I think the most possible reason is caused by the Microsoft Integration Runtime Configuration Manager. I don't know if the error is solved now,  you could restart it and Data factory and try again.

Hope this helps.